# laravel 5 removing public from url not working on WAMP

Tags: laravel

Many people post that following htaccess works for removing "public" from url. But i am working on WAMP and this is not working:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

This shows following Error message from Laravel framework:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

There are other methods to remove "public" from url but I want to understand why this method is not working on my side which people followed frequently in their posts. my url is : http://localhost/laravel/  (directory: d:/wamp/www/laravel)

Can any one help me to understand why this popular method is not working on my side? Is their any issue in Laravel internal routing as I think my htaccess is working properly?

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: create a virtual host

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this is not exactly what you wanted but... Instead of rewriting the path, go to your Apache config and change your directory so it includes /public as well. That way you will get rid of the now necessary public from the URL. I know it is not an answer to your question, so please do not downvote. Nevertheless, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your router is not picking up the redirected path because your laravel installation is a subdirectory within your webserver and the RewriteRule `^(.*)$` is picking up the whole path which includes `/laravel`. This is being appended to `public/` because it's captured in `$1`.

The simplest case for you may be to alter the RewriteRule to not capture the `laravel` directory.

eg:

`ReqriteRule ^laravel/(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

> You may or may not need a forward slash `^/laravel/(.*)$ ...`

Alternatively, (and more correctly) you should setup a virtual host within your apache configuration to serve the laravel application in the root of a virtual host (as it's designed) **or** you might be better off in the long run using [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) as a preconfigured development environment.